# Stripe subscriptions creation when you already have a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

In my case - I am using Stripe with Rails, and a user can pay for something as a one-off 'Charge', or subscribe and have a certain amount of the things they would have been charged for each time, for free, per month.

Once you create a charge - I save the `stripe_customer_id` in my PG database.

However if the user then wants to go onto a subscription, I would like to add it onto the Stripe customer, not create a new one.

If creating a new one it goes something like this:

```
customer_data = {
  email: params[:stripeEmail],
  card: params[:stripeToken]
}.merge(
  (monthly_plan.payment_offerings_plan.blank?) ?
    {} : { plan: Payment_offering.find(monthly_plan.payment_offerings_plan).stripe_plan_id }
)

customer = Stripe::Customer.create customer_data
```

So essentially - how do I add a subscription in Stripe to an already existing Stripe Customer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of this can be found in the excellent [Ruby API Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby).  There are a few steps involved, but it's not so hard.  It may take a little experimentation to get it working in your application

## Create a Default Source

The customer must have a default source assigned for subscription charges to be made.  This can be created from a token, like so:

```
customer.sources.create({:source => token_id})
```

or assigned from a customer's existing cards, if you've already assigned cards to the user:

```
customer.default_source = customer.sources.retrieve(card_id)
```

## Create a Subscription Plan

You can easily create the Subscription Plan on the Stripe console, since this is typically a one-time activity; building out a UI to manage Subscription Plans is almost certainly overkill unless you have admin users that can manage subscription plans, but shouldn't have access to the Stripe console.

To programmatically create a Subscription Plan, try this:

```
Stripe::Plan.create(
  :amount => 4200,         #<== Amount is in cents, not dollars
  :interval => "month",
  :name => "Purple Plan",
  :currency => "usd",
  :id => "purple"
)
```

You can create as many plans as you'd like, and can subscribe the user to any that they like.

## Create a Subscription for the Customer

At this point, you can create the subscription on the customer, and this will initiate the billing process.

```
Stripe::Subscription.create(
  :customer => customer,
  :plan => "purple"
)
```

## Set up a Web Hook Receiver

For some reason, this documentation is in a different location (see [Webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)), but it's a very necessary part of the process.  This will keep your application advised of the

def PaymentController
  protect_from_forgery :except => :webhook

def webhook
    # Capture the event information from the webhook params
    event_id = params[:event]

```
# Verify that the event isn't forged to your Stripe account
event = Stripe::Event.retrieve(event_id)

# Record the event
PaymentEvents.create!(event)

# Handle the event in terms of your application
#...
```

end
end

The types of events sent from Stripe are documented at [Types of Events](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types).  You may choose to capture and handle some, while letting others pass.  However, in my applications, I've found it's better to capture and log all events, and then handle them as you need.  This way, if you missed handling an event that later becomes important to have handled, you have the event to refer to and can deal with it post hoc.

## Collect a Regular Payment

This is the easy part, and may best be done with your favorite cold beverage.  All you need to do from this point is monitor the Stripe console and your bank account.  No additional action required, because Stripe takes care of the rest.